# Slicing strings and adding the integers, Loop trouble

Tags: string, python-3.x, while-loop

My assignment is to chop apart sequences of numbers with dashes and add each piece together (ex: 1-1-1 = 3, 2-2 = 4). I don't know why my loop terminates after the first run through though. The output right now is

```
3
456
456
56-234
0
456
```

Here is the function:

```
def SSN(str):
    total = 0
    y = -1
    dash = 0
    while dash >= 0:
        dash = str.find("-")
        print(dash)
        if dash > -1:
            section = str[0:dash]
            str = str[dash+1:]
            section = int(section)
            print(section)
            total += section
            print(total)
            print(str)
        else:
            total = str
        y+=1
        print(y)
        return total

print(SSN("456-56-234"))
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement in your loop.  It's not possible for the loop to ever reach its second iteration.  Possibly those last two lines of the function shouldn't be indented that far.

Comment: `sum(int(chunk) for chunk in string.split('-'))`

Comment: Thanks! Both comments helped a lot. I'm not sure how to give credit for the best answer and all though.. :/ It would be Jason if I could find out how to do it.